# Symfony 3 returns wrong query results when using left join on Many-To-Many table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a two Entities with one many to many table. What I want to achieve is to fetch records that doesn't exist in many to many table.

In my scenario I have bus vehicles entity and station (travel destination) price. User can define price for each station and select bus vehicles that is applied to that route (or station). I want to get bus vehicles that is not selected for desired station (or route)

Here is bus vehicles (shorted version) entity:

```
/**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="StationStandardPrice", mappedBy="busVehicles", cascade={"persist"})
     */

    private $busVehicleGroup;
```

Station entity (shorted):

```
/**
     *  Many station can have many bus vehicles
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BusVehicle", inversedBy="busVehicleGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="standard_station_price_bus_groups",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="station_standard_price_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/

    private $busVehicles;
```

Controller:

```
 $busVehicles = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:BusVehicle")
                ->createQueryBuilder('bv')
                ->addSelect('sp')
                ->leftJoin('bv.busVehicleGroup', 'sp')
                ->where('bv.company = :company')
                ->andWhere ('sp.id IS NULL')//When I remove this line I get buses that is already selected
                ->andWhere('sp.departureStation = :departureStation')
                ->andWhere('sp.destinationStation = :destinationStation')
                ->andWhere('bv.passengerSeatsNumber BETWEEN :minPassenger AND :maxPassenger')
                ->setParameter('company', $company)
                ->setParameter('departureStation', $request->request->get('departureStation'))
                ->setParameter('destinationStation', $request->request->get('destinationStation'))
                ->setParameter('minPassenger', $request->request->get('minPassenger'))
                ->setParameter('maxPassenger', $request->request->get('maxPassenger'))
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();



            //$redirectUrl = $request->request->get('redirectUrl');
            dump ($busVehicles);

            return $this->json(['busVehicles' => $busVehicles]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The join table is not query-able using DQL (or QueryBuilder) because is not entity, can make this type of query only using sql. Then, my recommendation in order to simplify the query is get the buss already selected, and then find in bus table all bus not included on that list.

Modify your first query to get list of all selected bus ids, then get the list of bus not matching these ids.

```
$em->getRepository("AppBundle:BusVehicle")
           ->createQueryBuilder('bv')
           ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('bv.id', $selectedBusIds))
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
```